# RPC: Unknown Protocol

Tags: protocols, rpc

We are developing a RPC system with client in ubuntu system and server in Solaris system.

Currently we are struck at this error: "RPC: Unknown Protocol"

can some one help us with this?

Comment: You're gonna have to give more effort, man.

No one knows what you've done or not done yet.

Answer (score 4):

Change "visible" to "tcp" in clnt_create() call.

Comment: Thank you! Great job inferring the issue of misdirecting, ancient documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Run your program with strace to see if you are missing any critical files. In my case, it made me realize that I was missing libnss_files and libnss_dns libraries, and the problem went away once I added them.